# How can I export an object to multiple scales at once?

Tags: scripting, scale

Let's say our objet is a ring.

I model it in size 1.
I need to generate 60 other rings sizes by scaling my first model it with predetermined ratios stored in a table.

Is there a way to automatise this ?

I did not find a plugin or script for it.

I still can't write a script by my own but I could modifiy a similar script that exist in order to adapt it to my needs.

Could you help on this topic ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say export, I expect you need it in a non-blender format, say for 3D printing. Most export options have a scale parameter that can easily save each export in a different size.

```
import bpy

ring_sizes = [0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6]

for s in ring_sizes:
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.ply(filepath="Ring_"+str(s)+".ply", global_scale=s)
```

Comment: Thanks sambler ! I adapted it and made it available here if other people need it : http://crea.coffee/16390/blender-script-rescale-export-3d-multiple-sizes/